# Почему ПО не видит JDK 10 версии?

Tags: netbeans, java

Я заметил давно эту проблему, но сейчас она повторилась и я хочу узнать о ней подробнее. Все началось с того, что я устанавливал *Android Studio*, для нее, как известно, нужно *jdk*. Первый раз установил **последнюю** версию, точнее десятку. Что-то пошло не так, *gradle* по возмущался и я установил **восьмую** версию. Тогда на это не обратил внимание, так как и без этого проблем хватало. Сегодня помогал в установке **Netbeans** (!). Экзешник начинал установку, но, через пару секунд все улетало, так как он не видел *jdk*. Мы около часа копались и нашли проблему (заменили **10** на **8** версию), точнее установили ПО, но проблема так и осталось для меня за семью замками. **Вывод**: ПО не видит *jdk* **десятой версии**. Кто может объяснить данный парадокс?

P.S. Все скачивали с официального сайта, учитывая системные требования, устанавливали в нужных местах.

Comment: Мне помогал наш ментор, но причину он назвать не смог.

Comment: в девятке ввели модульный jdk. Netbeans актуальной версии?

Comment: Да, самый новый.

Comment: Скачивали для 64х версии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans 8.2 не будет работать с Java версии более 8. Можете скачать Netbeans 9 с сайта Apache, но пока она только для Java SE. Родных модулей для JEE для NetBeans 9 пока нет.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans для 9 версии надо качать отдельно с сайта apache (https://netbeans.apache.org). Они заявляют поддержку 10 версии, но не занимаюсь разработкой Java, поэтому не вникал. IDE полностью портабельная и не требует никакой установки. За исключением настройки расположение пакета jdk